# How to achieve no outside margins for floats in a div

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML / CSS basics and I am stuck at the following problem.
I would like to put 3 fixed-size float divs in a fixed-width outside div, and I would only like to have margins between them, not outside them.

My problem is that I don't know how to achieve this. I tried reading about margin-collapse and negative margins but it is quite hard for me to understand.

I have put my example onto the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6dqR6/

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="articles">
         <h2>header</h2>

        <div class="article">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <p>5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <p>6</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.articles {
    height: 1500px;
    background-color: #fcdda1;
}
.article {
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #4ecac3;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

Can you tell me:

1. What is the recommended way to solve my problem and fix the above example?
2. Possibly some beginner friendly articles/books from which I could learn about it?

Thanks a lot, and sorry for asking such a beginner level question here.

Comment: I suggest using Chrome's Inspect Element (or Firebug in FF).  With that you can see exactly how your CSS is behaving, plus edit it in real-time to see how changes will look.  You're going to find the CSS, even for people that know what they're doing, is a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Hello @planktone, if you find the answer that solves your needs, please mark this answer as "accepted", so the issue is closed. See the [StackOverflow guide](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) about it.

Comment: Firefox 3D view will help out any "noobie" to visually understand what all of your elements are doing and behaving like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1) Solution for a basic CSS knowledge

#### Based on Css2, fully cross-browser

Here is the solution to have only the inner margin, and not applied to the last on the right, click here, the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dqR6/2/).

You have to make a mask to overflow the plus margin:

```
.outer {
  width: 940px;
  overflow:hidden;
  /*behaves like a mask*/
}
.articles {
  width: 960px; /*set the actual width: 320*3*/
}
```

## 2) Advanced solution

#### Based on Css3, only modern browser (except, of course, IE)

The Css `nth-child` solution is here in this example: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/6dqR6/3/):

```
.articles > :nth-child(3n+1) { margin-right: 0; }
```

You can find [here the complete explanation](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) about how it works.

Since IE have a [partial support](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3) of Css3 upcoming standards, you can use [IE conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to pass specific Css on for InternetExplorer legacy versions (e.g. Css3 Solution for modern browsers, Css2 solution only for old IEs).

Eventually, [**here are other solutions**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-margins-first-element/) based on Css pseudoclass and jQuery.

## 3) Online resources to make practice on CSS

Here is where you can learn a lot about Css in general:

[CssTricks](http://css-tricks.com/)

[Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/)

[Tuts Plus: CSS categories](http://code.tutsplus.com/categories/css)

Comment: A simple "last" class would be adequate for the situation also as a beginner/intermediate level solution.

Comment: @Michael: i'm not agree. How do you implement it to achieve the result? Could you try to provide a Fiddle to test it?

Comment: This is a rough mock-up: http://jsfiddle.net/6dqR6/4/  It would work better if everything was calculated with percentages.  Like this... http://jsfiddle.net/6dqR6/5/

Comment: @Michael: totally agree with your last example, the one with the percent value layout. About the first demo, with the 'last' CSS class, it's correct, but it's not really mantenaible: it would better to assign the CSS class with JS/jQuery, not hardcoded in the HTML, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This can be thought as "advanced", but I think is the best way, just add to your CSS:

```
.article:nth-child(3n-3) {
   margin-right:0 
}
```

This makes every third element not having right margin, so it wont fall to the next line. That's it.

Beside [CssTricks](http://css-tricks.com), [Mozilla Developer Network](http://developer.mozilla.org) is a good resource to learn too.